# Unable to send form data to web api using postasync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send sourceFile value to web api. But in API i am receiving is null

```
var formVars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
formVars.Add("sourceFile", "Helloo");

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formVars);                   

var result = client.PostAsync("ImageApi/Compare", content).Result;
string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
return Content(resultContent);
```

API code

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult Compare(string sourceFile)
{
   return Ok(sourceFile);
}
```

I am using DotNet core 2.0

Comment: you may Try to post data using postman. If you get successfull, you can use fiddler to compare both sides to see difference

Comment: Why are you using `HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formVars);` and not `var content = new StringContent("{ \"sourceFile\": \"Helloo\" }", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")`

Comment: I tried the json as well still no luck

Comment: Maybe the path is not correct `"ImageApi/Compare"`

Comment: path is correct because if i return data from api it comes back

Comment: If you do it that way you could try making your argument a `FormDataCollection` instead of `string`. On this link scroll down [to Collecting POST values with FormDataCollection](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/16/Mapping-UrlEncoded-POST-Values-in-ASPNET-Web-API#Collecting-POST-values-with-FormDataCollection). Although I can't see the point in using a Dictionary for sending one value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to await the result, do not try to access .Result yourself. The call would not have completed at that point.

you need to use something like this:

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formVars);                   

var result = await client.PostAsync("ImageApi/Compare", content);
result .EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This is based on your code and hasn't been tested but should set you on the right path to get this working. Don't ever try to do async stuff by accessing .Result.

One more thing, you need to use a model as well.

create a model class, which has all the properties you add in your dictionary.

in your case it will be something like :

```
public class MyModel{
     public string sourceFile { get ;set; }
}
```

your controller becomes:

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult Compare([FromBody]MyModel model)
{
   return Ok(model.sourceFile);
}
```

Comment: While good advice, it is not true that `.Result` would not work. Since OP states a null is observed it is clear the call makes it into the controller and has nothing to do with blocking the async call.